# Cauchy Integral Theorem over a square root

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

How do I evaluate 
$$
\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\sqrt z\mathrm{d} z
$$  using Cauchy's Integral Theorem?

Comment: $\oint\sqrt z = \oint z$ since the magnitude of each complex number is $1$, and the curve has to cover the entire unit circle.

Comment: Be care full complex square root does not extend an an analytic function on the complex plane :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the principal branch of $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$, which has a branch cut on the negative real axis, you have $\sqrt{e^{i\theta}} = e^{i\theta/2}$ for $-\pi < \theta < \pi$, so your integral is
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i\theta/2} i e^{i\theta} d\theta = - 4 i/3$$
To do this using Cauchy's theorem, you deform your contour to one that goes from $-1$ to $0$ just below the branch cut, and then back to $-1$ just above the branch cut, thus
$$ 2 (-i) \int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{-t}\; dt = -4\pi i/3$$

Comment: >To do this using Cauchy's theorem, you deform your contour

Why and how does one do that?

Comment: @carlos1251 See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_%E2%80%93_branch_cuts).